# Hudson Maven Release Tagging Server certificate verification failed

Tags: hudson, maven-release-plugin

I already googled a lot and found similar posts but I couldnt get my release plugin to work 100%.

The release plugin is running until tagging the release. Updating the poms in prepare works but tagging fails. The url is exactly the same:

> [INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
>   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username user--password  --no-auth-cache --non-interactive commit --file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-527854298.commit --targets C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1649111498782212601-targets"
>   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Hudson\jobs\project\workspace
>   [INFO] Tagging release with the label project-1.0...
>   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username user --password  --no-auth-cache --non-interactive copy --file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-185331125.commit --revision 10608 https://server:3691/svn/Repository/project https://server:3691/svn/Repository/project/tags/framework-1.0"
>   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Hudson\jobs\project\workspace

I really dont understand why the plugin is able to update the poms but not able to checkin the tag files.

I already tried to access the repository localy with cmd and accepted everything permanentely.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2, SVN 1.5.7(due to old server) and Hudson 2.2.0 deployed on Tomcat 6.0. Can't enable default --trust-server-cert as svn doesnt support this in my version. Tomcat is running on exactly the same user I accepted the svn certificates on command line.

Can somebody let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have got permission to create files under the `/tags` directory in the repository? You should try executing the second tagging command in a Command Prompt window and see what happens. (If you've got any error messages, please paste them here).